# Adjoint of creation and anihilation operators and problem with expected values of $\hat a$ and $\hat a^{\dagger}$ for coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, coherent-states

The definition of the adjoint operator of an operator $\hat A$ is

\begin{equation}
(\vec x|\hat A \vec y) = (\hat A \vec x| \vec y) \quad \forall x, y \in \mathcal{H}
\end{equation}

where $(\cdot|\cdot)$ is the inner product of a Hilbert space.

So before this definition came into play, I innocently tried to do the expected values of $\hat a$ and $\hat a^\dagger$ for the coherent state $\left|\alpha\right>$, getting:

\begin{equation}
\left<\alpha\right|\hat a \left|\alpha\right> = \alpha \left<\alpha|\alpha\right> = \alpha
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\left<\alpha\right|\hat a^\dagger \left|\alpha\right> = \alpha^* \left<\alpha|\alpha\right> = \alpha^*
\end{equation}

which I think are correct.

But then, I thought that the expected value of $\hat a$ and $\hat a^\dagger$ should be the same, since one is the transposed complex-conjugated operator of the other, and that *usually* means that one is the adjoint of the other, but with the definition of adjoint operator and getting different values for the brakets I did before, it's clear that they're not their adjoint.

So my question is:

- Did I suppose or do anything wrong? Is this definition I gave for adjoint operator not applicable to this case?
- If it's correct, do $\hat a$ and $\hat a^\dagger$ have any operator corresponding to its adjoint, or if the transposed complex-conjugated operator of $\hat A$ is not the adjoint of $\hat A$ then $$\hat A$ doesn't have an adjoint operator?
- If they do have an adjoint, which are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with what you did except with your incorrect notion that the expectation values and its adjoint should be the same.

Indeed you have just shown that, for $\hat a$ and $\hat a^\dagger$, one is the complex conjugate of the other.  One intuitive way to see this is to remember that, up to constants
$$
\hat a\sim \hat x+i\hat p\, , \qquad 
\hat a^\dagger \sim \hat x -i \hat p \tag{1}
$$
with $\hat x$ and $\hat p$ self-adjoint, so their expectations values are real.  Using this together with Eq.(1) clearly shows how one can anticipate that the expectation values of $\hat a$ and $\hat a^\dagger$ will be complex conjugate in pairs.

Answer (score 1):

The creation and annihilation operators are true adjoint operators, yes. In the case of the coherent state, we have

$$(\alpha|a^{\dagger}\alpha)=(a\alpha|\alpha)=a^{*}(\alpha|\alpha).$$

I think you may be forgetting that the complex inner product satisfies $(c\vec{v}|\vec{w})=c^{*}(\vec{v}|\vec{w})$ and not $(c\vec{v}|\vec{w})=c(\vec{v}|\vec{w})$.

If this isn't where your confusion lies, comment below or edit your question to more clearly explain why you think that $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ should have the same expectation value.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, then after seeing this answer, I think that maybe my problem is with the inner product. When doing $(a\alpha|\alpha)$ you're treating the first $\alpha$ as a ket? In my definition of adjoint, I thought that $(\hat A \vec x|\vec y)=<\vec x|\hat A|\vec y>$, but in your answer it doesn't seem like it... I don't quite get it

Comment: @Mr.Nobody - $({\hat A} \vec{x} | \vec{y} ) = \langle\vec{x} | {\hat A}^\dagger | \vec{y} \rangle$.

Comment: So my mistake was trying to translate the definition so I could understand it into $\left<x\right|A\left|y\right>=\left<y\right|A^\dagger\left|x\right>$ which seems that isn't always true am I right?